# kubectl returns "Unauthorized" when going through a reverse proxy

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubectl, pki

In my /root/.kube/config I have a server: value of "https://my.reverse.proxy:6443".

If I don't set any certificates on the reverse proxy (traffic goes directly to backend and backend certificate is presented, SSL passthrough), I can run a kubectl command successfully (i.e sudo kubectl get pods -o wide -A). But if I set a certificate on the reverse proxy, my kubectl command returns:

```
$ sudo kubectl --insecure-skip-tls-verify get pods -o wide -A
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Is it because the kubectl is trying to "authenticate" with the reverse proxy certificate, and is only allowed to do so with the back-end certificate?

How would I get rid of that error if I want to use a different certificate on the reverse proxy (no SSL passthrough)? What should I do on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

If the issue started after renewing kubernetes certificates, this caused the existing **~/.kube/config** to have outdated keys and certificate values in it.

The solution is to replace the values **client-certificate-data** and **client-key-data** in file **~/.kube/config** with the values from the updated file in **/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf** of the same name

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the client certificate was stripped by the reverse proxy (the reverse proxy certificate was sent to the Kubernetes server instead), and as a result didn't make it to the Kubernetes server. I need passthrough on my reverse proxy no matter what if I want my client certificates to authenticate properly.